# Updating a complex child from from a TPL task in the parent form

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am trying to upgrade my winforms application with a form that would display the progress of a time consuming task, but regardless of what I do the form does not work properly. Here is what I have:

- **Setup:**

There is a form (Form1) with one button and the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource cToken = null;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        using (Form2 form = new Form2())
        {
            form.Show(); //Shows the 'progress' form
            int i = 0;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (cToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested == false && i <= 5) //Runs the task until it is cancelled or has reached its end
                {

                    form.UpdateProgress(i); //Updates the 'progress' form
                    Thread.Sleep(500); //Waits simulating time consuming activity
                    i++;
                }
            }, cToken.Token, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is another form (Form2) that is displayed by Form1 when a time consuming operation is running:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar1.Step = 1;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 6;
    }

    public void UpdateProgress(int i)
    {
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            label1.Text = string.Format("Step {0} of 6", i);
    }
}
```

This form has a progress bar, a label (shows the percentage) and a cancel button.

- **Expected behavior:**

When a time consuming operation is running, Form2 (the one with the progress bar) is to be shown and is expected to update the progress bar and the label text with each call of UpdateProgress(). At the same moment neither of the forms should be or appear to be blocked so that the user can cancel the time consuming task at any time.

- **Current behavior:**

Form2 is shown, the progress bar updates properly, but other controls are not displayed and both forms are blocked.

- **Additional information:**

I am using C# 4.0 so I cannot use Progress and I would like to avoid using BackgroundWorker or events (not that I don't like them, I just want to use TPL this time).

- **The question:**

Is there I way I can achieve my goal using TPL? I've been googling and reading MSDN docs for days already but so far have not found a working solution. I've come across many topics here on stackoverflow, but they mostly show how to asynchronously update a progress bar within the same form and I can make it work, but it isn't what I really need. I am pretty sure I am missing something but I can't figure out what.

Comment: You can add the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package to your project to add `async/await` and `Progress<T>` support to your application even though it's .NET 4.0 and clean up the continuations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code starts a new tash *on the UI thread* with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` and then calls `.Wait()` on it.

You need to remove both `.Wait()` and `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. Inside the child form's `UpdateProgress` you should make the appropriate `Invoke` calls to update the progress bar, or use `Task.StartNew` on the UI thread *there* to update the UI.

You should also consider adding the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) package to your project, which adds `async/await` and `Progress<T>` support to .NET 4.0 projects. This will allow you to clean up the code considerably.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me realize how obvious the solution was. I've removed the 'wait()' and 'TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()', but then I noticed form2 disappearing very quickly. So I went further and removed the 'using(Form2 form = new Form2)' block, because of it the form was disposed of before my task could do anything in it (hence the Wait()), then I added invokes to form2 and now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The .Wait() on the end of your thread is what is causing the Synchronous behavior.

Comment: I've removed the Wait() part and that has unblocked the parent form, the child (Form2) form is still blocked and the only rendered object on this form is still the progress bar? Am I missing something?

Comment: EDIT: Wouldn't it be better to pass the task as an argument to Form2 and start it from within the form itself?